# Querying these three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to query these three tables and count the number of households in a community that have machinery id of 1 from these three tables:

```
machinery [hhmachineryid -      hhid                - machineryid]
                     1            10-10-009-0001                7
                     1           10-07-005-0001                7
                     2            10-02-054-0001                3

household table [       hhid-         hh_comm_code ] 
                   10-01-001-0001        10-01-001
                   10-01-001-0002        10-01-001

community table [ communitycode   -       community]
                   10-01-001              sekondi
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags, but the question is still not complete.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? Can you show us your current query attempt!

Comment: COMMUNITY COMMUNITYCODE AND TOTAL NUMBER OF A SPECIFIC MACHINERY

Comment: With your example data, the query will return no data. a) you have no machinery with a machinery ID of 1; b) you have no hhid in machinery that would match a hhid in your household table. Can you supply data where a join could succeed?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - but it returns no data with your input:

```
WITH
machinery(hhmachineryid,hhid,machineryid) AS (
          SELECT 1,'10-10-009-0001',7
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'10-07-005-0001',7
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'10-02-054-0001',3
)
,
household(hhid,hh_comm_code) AS ( 
          SELECT '10-01-001-0001','10-01-001'
UNION ALL SELECT '10-01-001-0002','10-01-001'
)
,
community(communitycode,community) AS (
SELECT '10-01-001','sekondi'
)
SELECT
  community
, communitycode
, COUNT(*) AS household_count
FROM community c
JOIN household h
  ON c.communitycode = h.hh_comm_code
JOIN machinery m
  ON h.hhid = m.hhid
WHERE c.community='sekondi'
  AND m.machineryid=1
GROUP BY
  community
, communitycode
;
```

Comment: MICROSOFT SQL 2014